Npm i installing dev dependency using omit=dev flag
I am trying npm install on a helloworld node js application with the environment set to production. It is installing dev dependency even if the environment is set to production. Is there anything I am missing out on?
"devDependencies": {
  "c8xxxxx": "^10.0.0",
   "gaxios": "^6.0.0",
   "mocha": "^10.0.0",
   "sinon": "^18.0.0",
   "supertest": "^7.0.0",
   "wait-port": "^1.0.4",
   "abcd": "^1.0.0"
}

This is what my devdependencies in package.json looks like and just to check I have added c8xxxxx as an invalid dependency.
And command I am using is npm install --omit=dev
I expected that dev dependencies shouldn't be installed
